How to get Type:FUNC and its name from a ELF file?
include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <elf.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <elf_file>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("Opening ELF file");
        return 1;
    }
    Elf32_Ehdr ehdr;
    if (read(fd, &ehdr, sizeof(ehdr)) != sizeof(ehdr)) {
        perror("Reading ELF header");
        close(fd);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("e_type:%d\n", ehdr.e_type);
    printf("e_machine:%d\n", ehdr.e_machine);
    printf("e_section_off:%d\n", ehdr.e_shoff);
    printf("e_section_num:%d\n", ehdr.e_shnum); 
    Elf32_Shdr symtab_hdr;
    for (int i = 0; i < ehdr.e_shnum; i++) {
        Elf32_Shdr shdr;
        lseek(fd, ehdr.e_shoff + i * ehdr.e_shentsize, SEEK_SET); // seek offset
        read(fd, &shdr, sizeof(shdr));
        if (shdr.sh_type == SHT_SYMTAB) {
            symtab_hdr = shdr;
            printf("index:%d, symtab_offset:%x\n",i , symtab_hdr.sh_offset);
            break;
        }
    }

    Elf32_Shdr strtab_hdr;
    for (int i = 0; i < ehdr.e_shnum;i++) {
        Elf32_Shdr shdr;
        lseek(fd, ehdr.e_shoff + i * ehdr.e_shentsize, SEEK_SET); // seek offset
        read(fd, &shdr, sizeof(shdr));

        if (shdr.sh_type == SHT_STRTAB) {
            strtab_hdr = shdr;
            printf("index:%d, strtab_offset:%x\n",i, strtab_hdr.sh_offset);
            break;
        }
    }

    close(fd);
    return 0;
}

I get symbal table, but when I want to get string table, I get other Type is also SHT_STRTAB.
e_type:3
e_machine:3
e_section_off:13780
e_section_num:29
index:26, symtab_offset:3034
index:6, strtab_offset:28c

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .interp           PROGBITS        00000194 000194 000013 00   A  0   0  1
  [ 2] .note.gnu.bu[...] NOTE            000001a8 0001a8 000024 00   A  0   0  4
  [ 3] .note.ABI-tag     NOTE            000001cc 0001cc 000020 00   A  0   0  4
  [ 4] .gnu.hash         GNU_HASH        000001ec 0001ec 000020 04   A  5   0  4
  [ 5] .dynsym           DYNSYM          0000020c 00020c 000080 10   A  6   1  4
  [ 6] .dynstr           STRTAB          0000028c 00028c 0000a6 00   A  0   0  1
  [ 7] .gnu.version      VERSYM          00000332 000332 000010 02   A  5   0  2
  [25] .comment          PROGBITS        00000000 003008 00002b 01  MS  0   0  1
  [26] .symtab           SYMTAB          00000000 003034 000280 10     27  18  4
  [27] .strtab           STRTAB          00000000 0032b4 000222 00      0   0  1
  [28] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 0034d6 0000fc 00      0   0  1

So how to get locate to .strtab accurately and use .strtab and symbal tables to find which is FUNC and get its "name"(this is offset, then get real name in strtab) ?
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 40 entries:
   Num:    Value  Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND 
     1: 00000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS Scrt1.o
     2: 000001cc    32 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT    3 __abi_tag
     3: 00000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS crtstuff.c
     4: 000010b0     0 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   14 deregister_tm_clones
     5: 000010f0     0 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   14 register_tm_clones

I try to use .shstrtab to find section headers name. But it is STRTAB as well.
